# Android Studio: Translation Editor not showing Default Value and translation

Tags: android, android-studio

The Translation Editor of my Android Studio does not work properly. If I open the translation editor does list the correct keys of the strings, however the default values and the translations can not be found. All keys have a default value and most of them have a translation, too.

[image]

I restarted Android Studio, performed a clean and rebuild, however the translation editor does not work. Any ideas or suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try **File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart ..**
It solved the same issue with me ..

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Translations Editor didn't show my other languages too. But my problem was I had empty strings.xml files for those languages. I mean, like following:

```
<resources>
</resources>
```

Once I added some string in those files, even if they were empty, it began appearing in Translations Editor, such as following:

```
<resources>
    <string name="any_string" />
</resources>
```

Although you might need to click on refresh button at Translations Editor to update the view.

Comment: Worked for me. I had to check all the packages, add any string or delete the file, then invalidate the cache and restart, then worked like before.